# Wordpress-Restricting parts of a post to specific users

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a site that is going to be used by Real estate agents, Brokers, and apt. hunters to locate and lease apartments. I need the brokers to be able to add showing instructions to their listing that agents can view but not edit and the public cannot view.

I am using a "real estate" theme that has gotten me 2/3 of the way there but this added functionality that I require doesn't seem to be able to be plugged into the theme with... a plug in. I've tried Advanced custom fields, members, and numerous other role, and custom field plug ins. I was convinced that this project would or could be supported by some existing plugin or widget but am now not so sure.

If anyone has experience with this please throw me a bone. I dont expect code examples but just a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the theme uses custom roles for brokers/agents etc, why not add a custom field to the listing editor screen, then use an if current_user_can capability check in the template to display it.

e.g

```
<?php if( current_user_can( ' edit_listing ' ) : ?>
    <?php echo get_field( ' instructions ' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```